# Hiding other menu-items when hovering over one - messes with my css-transitions

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a menu act in a very particular way:
1) submenu transitionally appears when its menu point is hovered
2) after moving the mouse away again, the submenu remains for a second before transitionally disappearing
3) if I hover another menu item, any remaining submenu (that hasn't transitioned away yet) will disappear instantly.

I have been trying to do this for a while, but I keep running into bugs that I can't explain.

The HTML (yes, I just made some divs rather than a list):

```
    <div class="menu">
<div class="menu-item" id="item-1">
  Item 1
  <div class="menu-child" id="child-1">Child 1</div>
 </div>

 <div class="menu-item" id="item-2">
  Item 2
  <div class="menu-child" id="child-2">Child 2</div>
 </div>

 <div class="menu-item" id="item-3">
  Item 3
  <div class="menu-child" id="child-3">Child 3</div>
 </div>
 </div>
```

The CSS:

```
.menu-item .menu-child {
  margin-top:10px;
  border:1px solid #000000;
  height:22px;
  visibility:hidden;
  opacity:0;
  -webkit-transition: visibility 1s 1s, opacity 1s 1s;
  transition: visibility 1s 1s, opacity 1s 1s;
}

.menu-item:hover .menu-child {
  visibility:visible;
  opacity:1;
  -webkit-transition: visibility 1s, opacity 1s;
  transition: visibility 1s, opacity 1s;
}

.menu {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display:flex;
}

.menu-item {
  display:inline-block;
  width:32%;
  padding-left:20px;
  background:none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

The Javascript:

```
  $('#item-1').hover(
    function() {
    $("#child-2, #child-3").hide();
    },
    function() {
    $("#child-2, #child-3").show();
    }
);
   $('#item-2').hover(
    function() { 
    $("#child-1, #child-3").hide();
    },
    function() { 
    $("#child-1, #child-3").show();
    }
);
   $('#item-3').hover(
    function() { 
    $("#child-2, #child-1").hide();
    },
    function() { 
    $("#child-1, #child-2").show();
    }
);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zyu9rum9/5/
In this case the menu is acting ALMOST exactly the way I want it. It's doing all those three things that I asked for, but if I go straight from one menu item to another, the incoming one appears without its intended CSS transition.
I suspected this might be due to the newly-displayed submenu changing to :hover BEFORE the jQuery .mouseLeave() function (as in the second part of my .hover function) has executed .show() on the "incoming" submenu. The element appearing IN its :hover state, it makes sense that there is nothing to transition to/from.

So I tried to fix this, by executing .show() on all other submenus BEFORE leaving a submenu. Did this by adding .show() after .hide() with a slight delay.
https://jsfiddle.net/wtd5pxvs/2/

The new JS:

```
  $('#item-1').mouseenter(
    function() {
    $("#child-2, #child-3").hide(0).delay(10).show(10);
    }
);
   $('#item-2').mouseenter(
    function() {
    $("#child-1, #child-3").hide(0).delay(10).show(10);
    }
);
   $('#item-3').mouseenter(
    function() {
    $("#child-2, #child-1").hide(0).delay(10).show(10);
    }
);
```

Now THIS works EXACTLY how I want it to. Except only on some of the submenus.
For the life of me, I can't figure out WHY some of them don't get hidden when supposed to. I can't see a pattern in which ones are affected by this "bug" (which I'm currently calling it to ease my own temper).

(Menu item 1 only hides submenu 3, item 2 only hides 3, and item 3 only hides 2 - it's ridiculous).

I've tried so many different solutions. For instance, moving all transitions (visibility and opacity) to be part of the .hover() function rather than a css :hover event.
Tried in all shapes and forms of .hover, .mouseenter, .mouseleave
Tried ditching .hide() and .show() altogether and just use visibility and opacity, but making the jQuery code alter the TRANSITION speeds and delays for each mouseevent. This just did entirely different things in entirely different browsers and simulators.

So now I'm tired. I feel thin, sort of stretched, like butter scraped over too much bread.

Help me, Stackoverflow. You're my only hope.

EDIT:
Here's how it looks if I make JS handle editing the transitions and not using .hide/.show at all:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#item-1').hover(
        function() {
        $("#child-1")
        .css("-webkit-transition", "visibility 1s, opacity 1s")
        .css("transition", "visibility 1s, opacity 1s"); 
        $("#child-2, #child-3")
        .css("-webkit-transition", "visibility 0s, opacity 1s")
        .css("transition", "visibility 0s, opacity 1s");
        },
        function() {
        $("#child-1, #child-2, #child-3")
        .css("-webkit-transition", "visibility 1s 1s, opacity 1s 1s")
        .css("transition", "visibility 1s 1s, opacity 1s 1s");
        }
    );
       $('#item-2').hover(
        function() { 
        $("#child-2")
        .css("-webkit-transition", "visibility 1s, opacity 1s")
        .css("transition", "visibility 1s, opacity 1s"); 
        $("#child-1, #child-3")
        .css("-webkit-transition", "visibility 0s, opacity 1s")
        .css("transition", "visibility 0s, opacity 1s");
        },
        function() { 
        $("#child-1, #child-2, #child-3")
        .css("-webkit-transition", "visibility 1s 1s, opacity 1s 1s")
        .css("transition", "visibility 1s 1s, opacity 1s 1s");
        }
    );
       $('#item-3').hover(
        function() { 
        $("#child-3")
        .css("-webkit-transition", "visibility 1s, opacity 1s")
        .css("transition", "visibility 1s, opacity 1s"); 
        $("#child-2, #child-1")
        .css("-webkit-transition", "visibility 0s, opacity 1s")
        .css("transition", "visibility 0s, opacity 1s"); 
        },
        function() {
        $("#child-1, #child-2, #child-3")
        .css("-webkit-transition", "visibility 1s 1s, opacity 1s 1s")
        .css("transition", "visibility 1s 1s, opacity 1s 1s");
        }
    );
        });
```

With CSS:

```
.menu-item .menu-child {
  margin-top:10px;
  border:1px solid #000000;
  visibility:hidden;
  opacity:0;
}

.menu-item:hover .menu-child {
  visibility:visible;
  opacity:1;
}
```

Stupid, right? Spent hours coming up with this just to find out that it's shit. Or was I closer than I thought?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll start by stressing the importance of writing concise questions on SO and the impact it has on their chances of getting answered. The best way I can think of is by presenting how I would have asked this question:

---

I'm trying to cancel the exiting transition effect on menu items when another sibling menu item is hovered. Here's what I have tried:

`<!-- /* your existing code here, added using the snippet tool */ -->`

> I think SO would have responded faster and better to your question if it would have been presented concisely. I might be wrong though. :)

---

Now, I am guessing the snippet below is what you came here for, right?

```js
$('.menu-item').on('mouseenter', function(){
 $('.menu-item').addClass('hide-children');
  $(this).removeClass('hide-children');
  setTimeout(function(){
   $('.menu-item').removeClass('hide-children');
  }, 42)
})
```

```css
/* Start of additional CSS */
.menu-item.hide-children .menu-child {
  display: none;
  -webkit-transition: visibility 0s linear 0s, opacity 0s linear 0s;
       -o-transition: visibility 0s linear 0s, opacity 0s linear 0s;
     -moz-transition: visibility 0s linear 0s, opacity 0s linear 0s;
          transition: visibility 0s linear 0s, opacity 0s linear 0s;
}
.menu-item.hide-children:hover .menu-child {
  display: block;
}
/* End of additional CSS 

Please note that in order to strictly fix your transition problem, all you need
is the CSS above added to your current CSS. You will also need the jQuery part.

However, I noticed your menu items were effectively pushing the content down 
(which, from my point of view shouldn't happen), so I took the liberty to 
change your markup a bit  and rewrite your CSS accordingly, just so you have 
an alternative.

*/

body {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
.menu {
  display:-webkit-box;
  display:-webkit-flex;
  display:-moz-box;
  display:-ms-flexbox;
  display:flex;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.menu-item {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1 0 auto;
     -moz-box-flex: 1;
      -ms-flex: 1 0 auto;
          flex: 1 0 auto;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.65);
  border-right: 1px solid transparent;
  -webkit-background-clip: content-box;
     -moz-background-clip: content-box;
       -o-background-clip: content-box;
          background-clip: content-box; 
  -webkit-transition: background-color .3s cubic-bezier(.4,0,.2,1), -webkit-box-shadow .1s linear; 
  transition: background-color .3s cubic-bezier(.4,0,.2,1), -webkit-box-shadow .1s linear; 
  -o-transition: background-color .3s cubic-bezier(.4,0,.2,1), box-shadow .1s linear; 
  -moz-transition: background-color .3s cubic-bezier(.4,0,.2,1), box-shadow .1s linear, -moz-box-shadow .1s linear; 
  transition: background-color .3s cubic-bezier(.4,0,.2,1), box-shadow .1s linear; 
  transition: background-color .3s cubic-bezier(.4,0,.2,1), box-shadow .1s linear, -webkit-box-shadow .1s linear, -moz-box-shadow .1s linear;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: 50px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}
.menu-item:last-child {
  border-right-width: 0;
}
.menu-item:hover {
  z-index: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.menu-item.fullWidthChildrenContainer {
  position: unset;
}
.children {
  border-top: 1px solid transparent;
  width: 100%;
}
.fullWidthChildrenContainer .children {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
}
.fullWidthChildrenContainer .children>* {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex-grow: 1;
     -moz-box-flex: 1;
      -ms-flex-positive: 1;
          flex-grow: 1;
  border-right-width: 1px;
}
.children>* {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  border: solid transparent;
  border-width: 0 0 1px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1),0 1px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.07),0 2px 1px -1px rgba(0,0,0,.06);
     -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1),0 1px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.07),0 2px 1px -1px rgba(0,0,0,.06);
          box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1),0 1px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.07),0 2px 1px -1px rgba(0,0,0,.06);
}
.children>*:last-child { border-right-width: 0;}

.menu-item:hover {
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1),0 1px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.07),0 2px 1px -1px rgba(0,0,0,.06);
     -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1),0 1px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.07),0 2px 1px -1px rgba(0,0,0,.06);
          box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1),0 1px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.07),0 2px 1px -1px rgba(0,0,0,.06);
}
.menu-item .menu-child {
  background-color: white;
  opacity:0;
  -webkit-transition: visibility 1s 1s, opacity 1s 1s;
  -o-transition: visibility 1s 1s, opacity 1s 1s;
  -moz-transition: visibility 1s 1s, opacity 1s 1s;
  transition: visibility 1s 1s, opacity 1s 1s;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-background-clip:padding-box;
     -moz-background-clip:padding-box;
       -o-background-clip:padding-box;
          background-clip:padding-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
}
.children {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
}
.children>.menu-child {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
.menu-item:hover .menu-child {
  opacity:1;
  -webkit-transition: visibility 1s, opacity 1s;
       -o-transition: visibility 1s, opacity 1s;
     -moz-transition: visibility 1s, opacity 1s;
          transition: visibility 1s, opacity 1s;
}

.menu-item: hover {
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.65);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu">
  <div class="menu-item fullWidthChildrenContainer" id="item-1">
    Item 1
    <div class="children">
      <div class="menu-child" id="child-11">Child 1-1</div>
      <div class="menu-child" id="child-12">Child 1-2</div>
      <div class="menu-child" id="child-13">Child 1-3</div>
      <div class="menu-child" id="child-14">Child 1-4</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-item" id="item-2">
    Item 2
    <div class="children">
      <div class="menu-child" id="child-21">Child 2-1</div>
      <div class="menu-child" id="child-22">Child 2-2</div>
      <div class="menu-child" id="child-23">Child 2-3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-item fullWidthChildrenContainer" id="item-3">
    Item 3
    <div class="children">
      <div class="menu-child" id="child-31">Child 3-1</div>
      <div class="menu-child" id="child-32">Child 3-2</div>
      <div class="menu-child" id="child-33">Child 3-3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: And thank you very much for the solution.
It works perfectly - and also comes with some sweet layout (I was just trying to keep my code here short - although this is one of my first attempts at CSS and jQuery, so I'm still learning a lot).

I actually found out, that my second version post here (the hide-delay-show one) works as a charm as well, as long you choose the right version of jQuery: strikes me as somewhat odd - I would expect simple handlers such as hide, delay and show to work uniformly throughout all jQuery libraries. Is there a simple explanation for this?

Comment: jQuery does not change such basic and widely spread methods. If they did, it would be documented on the method page properly. Of course, I might be wrong, but considering your limited experience, I am tempted to believe your initial code was slightly different from what you have now and some detail has changed since, making it work as expected. This is the cause in most cases, even for experienced coders, in CSS and JavaScript.

Comment: You're probably right about that ;) but it was specifically a change from 3.1.1 slim to 3.1.1 that made it work.

Comment: `3.1.1` is a version. `slim` is a package. If something does not exist in `slim` it doesn't necessarily mean it's not present or supported in  `3.1.1`. `slim` doesn't have all the methods. That's why they call it `slim`.